# "In this view" vs. "from this view"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

I wrote:

> In this view, a region is defined as an HTML fragment that shows information about one or more related items when it is rendered on a web browser.

Should it be:

> From this view, a region is defined as an HTML fragment that shows information about one or more related items when it is rendered on a web browser.

This is the previous text:

> ... These issues have motivated a number of researchers to work on region extractors as a means to relieve information extractors from the burden of analyzing many regions of a web document that do not contain any relevant information.

Comment: Why do you want to use "view"? Does it mean something like "in this technique"?

Comment: @card because I think it depends on how one views a web page. As some HTML tags or visual or conceptual regions (mainly data regions )

Comment: Consider _"In this model"_ instead. "From this _viewpoint_" is also idiomaic.

Comment: +1 From this viewpoint...  **model** and **view** are programming terms which might only serve to confuse

Comment: Why are you defining the term *after* you use it?

Comment: What does *one or more **related** items* mean?  What is *one related item* related to?  Do you mean to say "an item, or several related items"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo an item is related to another item. For example the title of a question is related to the body of a question. They could be several.

Comment: @Ahmad. You have missed the point.  What is one item related to if there is only one item?  **one or more related items** is a common but ultimately meaningless phrase. It simply adds meaningless verbosity, something resembling an idea but not quite being one.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo thanks, yeah "an Item, or several related items"

Answer (score 1):

**in this view** indicates that you are about to talk about the contents of the view, without any reference to who is observing it.

**from this view** indicates that some outside agent (a viewer, perhaps) is receiving information... from the view. For example,

> From this view, one can **get** the following information: ...

Note that the subject of the main clause is **one**... the person who is getting the information from the view.

In your sentence, the subject of the main clause is **region**, which is **not** getting anything from the view: you are simply defining what it is. **in this view** is therefore the correct form.